# Align image between viewing area with text on left and right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image in the middle of a web page with text on both sides. However, if I center the image it creates margins on both sides preventing text there. How can I center the image in the middle with text on both sides?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible code with your question so that it can be understood clearly, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add some code so we can help you some more, but a basic way of doing this would be like this. hope it helps.

```css
.child {
  width: 30%;
}

.child img{
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="child"> I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left I'm on the left </div>
<div class="child"><img src="https://w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg"></div>
<div class="child"> I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right I'm on the right </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great at image width of 100%. Is there a formula or something like that to determine the correct width for .child? 33.33% works at 100% but not at a smaller % for the image.

Comment: I simply took 100 divided by the number of divs you want next to each other.  In this case there were 3 divs.  So I used (roughly) 33%.  The width of the image being 100% is to tell the image to be 100% of the width of the div that it is inside of.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Text</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">your image here</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be using a CSS framework like Bootstrap. Please provide that info in your comment. People new to CSS won't know this and get frustrated about why solutions of others don't work for them.